# Limit number of tags in content

Tags: pelican

there is that old [blog post](https://www.onwebsecurity.com/configuration/generate-list-of-content-tags-for-pelican.html) to get a list of categories and tags from the content.

I only found tag_cloud as the only plugin dealing with tags no further mention in the documentation

Is there any way to limit the usable tags e.g. through the configs ?

Comment: You want to limit the number of tags or limit the usage of tags to the ones that is specified?

Comment: both would solve the problem. I just want to make sure that the number of tags go wild when to many people use pelican for a single page

Comment: I have suggested a solution below. There are other more strict ways, but they carry a certain amount of risk.

Comment: @justgoodin didn' finally hope for a solution. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is you can define a `ALLOWED_TAGS` variable in `pelicanconf.py` to contain the tags that you want to allow, then in places where tags are placed you can add a JINJA `if` block to allow only these tags

```
#pelicanconf.py

...

ALLOWED TAGS = ("tag1", "tag2", "tag3", tag4")
```

Example of generating tags for an article below

```
<div class="article-tags">
    {% for tag in article.tags %}
    {% if tag in ALLOWED_TAGS %}
    <a href="/tags/{{tag}}"><{{tag}}</span></a>
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```